# Does $x^3+k=y^2$ has infinite solution when $k \in \{1,2\}$?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

I am looking for results regarding power Diophantine equation  $x^3+k=y^2$ when $k \in \{1,2\}$? Does it have infinite integer solution?

If possible plz comment on  What happens when $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Please provide reference (any kind of online document is okay).

Edit: I have been told, $(x^3 - 1) + 2 = y^2$ has finitely many solutions,
$(x^3 - 1) + 1 = y^2$ has infinitely many solutions, where can I find about these solution?

Comment: This is Mordell's equation, apart from the case $k=0$ (negative $k$ are allowed as well) , only finite many integer solutions can exist.

Comment: for $k=1$, cf. [Mihailescu's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture)

Comment: @Peter just to confirm, for  both $k=1, k=2 $, the equation has finite solution?

Comment: Yes, and in these cases , all are known.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Is it true $(x^3 - 1) + 2 = y^2 $has finitely maly solutions,
$(x^3 - 1) + 1 = y^2$ has infinitely many solutions ?

Comment: @Peter plz look at the edit of my post.

Comment: @Andrew First of all, you can simply the equations to $$x^3+1=y^2$$ and $$x^3=y^2$$ I do not exactly remember where in the net the tables for the known solutions are, try to google it with the key words "mordell equation solutions". For a large range of $k$ , the list of solutions is known to be complete. But in general, the problem is difficult because the general upper bound for solutions is huge.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is trivial.

$(x^3 - 1) + 1 = y^2
$
is the same as
$x^3 = y^2
$
which has the infinite class of solutions
$x = n^2, y=n^3$
so that both sides are $n^6$.

Comment: Thanks, upvoted , does $(x^3 - 1) + 2 = y^2$  have finitely many solutions?

Comment: Yes, but I can't come up with the proof right now. Check the comments for a reference.

Comment: Strange! if i plot then I see finite intersection, could u explain why? https://ibb.co/hL8VPfj